# How to avoid broken part when git merging branches?

Tags: git

I imported an open Git repository (upstream/master) into my own repository (origin/master) and develop on the origin/master. Because upstream/master is active, lots of commits have been pushed into the branch since I cloned the repo; upstream/master and branch/master would look like below.

```
--o--o--M--...--N---...--O-----o   <- upstream/master
   \        
    A------B------C----- ... --D   <- branch/master
```

And if I merged the upstream into my master branch, it would look like the following:

```
--o--o--M--...--N---...--O-----o   <- upstream/master
   \        
    A---M--B----N-C------O--...--D <- master(upstream merged)
```

However, as the commits are interleaved when merging, if the commit N broke my master branch, the commits C-D would be broken. Although I could fix the branch with a new commit, the C-D part would be still broken.

How do I avoid the broken part? Or is there any best practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: How do you merge your branches? Usually you get merge commit. And if you checkout commit C again you don't have any changes from upstream after M in there. The whole point of a commit is that the code it points to does not change in retrospect. If you have  the same commit hash it cannot do anything different after a merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A merge doesn't rewrite any existing history, and it would actually be really difficult to create an "interleaved" history like you show in git.

If you start with this:

```
--X-----M-----N-----O-----P   <- upstream
   \        
    A------B------C------D   <- mybranch
```

Then a straight-forward merge of upstream into mybranch would create a new "merge commit", which:

- Applies the changes *both* branches have made since their last common ancestor (marked X)
- Has two "parent" commits, P and D, which is how git records history

So the result looks like this:

```
--X-----M-----N-----O-------P   <- upstream
   \                         \
    A------B------C------D----E   <- mybranch
```

From git's point of view, all the commits shown are "ancestors" of commit E, regardless of which branch they were on, but there is no direct relationship between, say C and N.

There *is* a way to merge code that recreates older changes, called "rebasing", which looks at each change you made, and creates a *new* commit pretending you made that change on top of P instead of X. It doesn't "interleave" commits, though, it puts all the new ones in order after the point you "rebase onto", giving something like this:

```
--X-----M-----N-----O-----P   <- upstream
                           \
                            A1------B1------C1------D1   <- mybranch
```

(It's tempting to think that commits A to E have "moved", but commits in git are immutable, and represent the state of the whole code, not a change, so commits A1 to E1 have to be created new by the "rebase" machinery.)

Comment: I see, that makes sense a lot; thank you for the great explanation ! BTW,  if `P` were mergeable but broke `mybranch`, I'd say that `mybranch` at `E` would be also broken after the merge. Is there any way to avoid this situation ? (Of course, I could fix `E` by `F`, though.)

Comment: @wanwan git doesn't know or care what your code _means_, it just knows how to compare and merge text files. If P contains an extra line of CSS that turns your homepage red, then E will have a red homepage; git can't know if that was a mistake, and you meant to turn it green. Similarly, there are what you might call "submarine" conflicts - two changes in different parts of the code that git doesn't know are related, but which between them cause a bug. The same thing could happen without any version control, if two people edited the code; at least git lets you find out _when_ it happened.

Comment: Thank you again. So, broken merge commits with such "submarine" conflicts are sometimes inevitable and have to be fixed in successive commits, right ?

Comment: @wanwan Correct. The only tool that can help you with those is a comprehensive automated test suite, which can help you spot them sooner, but ultimately bugs are a fact of life.